# AppCoordinator delegate through view controllers

Tags: swift, swift3, swift4

I'm trying to learn how the coordinator pattern works although i got some issues with the delegates from one child coordinator's view controller to another.
For example i have a home vc and i want to go to the details with one button, but i would like that to be managed from the HomeTabBarCoordinator with the following code.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    window = UIWindow()
    let tabBarController = UITabBarController()
    window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
    let about = HomeTabBarCoordinator()
    let one = deGenericize(about)
    let appCoordinator = TabAppCoordinator(tabBarController: tabBarController, tabs: [one])
    appCoordinator.start()

    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}

public protocol TabCoordinator {
    associatedtype RootType: UIViewController
    var rootController: RootType { get }
    var tabBarItem: UITabBarItem { get }
}

public class AnyTabCoordinator {
    var rootController: UIViewController
    var tabBarItem: UITabBarItem

    public init<T: TabCoordinator>(_ tabCoordinator: T) {
        rootController = tabCoordinator.rootController
        tabBarItem = tabCoordinator.tabBarItem
    }
}

public func deGenericize<T: TabCoordinator>(_ coordinator: T) -> AnyTabCoordinator {
    return AnyTabCoordinator(coordinator)
}

public class TabAppCoordinator {

    var tabBarController: UITabBarController
    var tabs: [AnyTabCoordinator]

    public init(tabBarController: UITabBarController, tabs: [AnyTabCoordinator]) {
        self.tabBarController = tabBarController
        self.tabs = tabs
    }

    public func start() {
        tabBarController.viewControllers = tabs.map { (coordinator) -> UIViewController in
            return coordinator.rootController
        }
    }

}
protocol HomeTabBarDelegate: class {
    func goToProfile()
}

class HomeTabBarCoordinator: NSObject, TabCoordinator {
    var rootController: UINavigationController
    var tabBarItem: UITabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "About", image: UIImage(named: "AboutTabBarIcon"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "AboutTabBarIcon_Filled"))
    let homeVC: HomeViewController

    override init() {
        self.homeVC = HomeViewController()
        self.rootController = UINavigationController()
        super.init()
        rootController.viewControllers = [homeVC]
        rootController.tabBarItem = tabBarItem
        homeVC.delegate = self //is being set properly when i add a breakpoint here
    }


}

extension HomeTabBarCoordinator: HomeTabBarDelegate {
    func goToProfile() { //never being executed
        let details = DetailsViewController()
        rootController.pushViewController(details, animated: true)
    }
}



class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: HomeTabBarDelegate?

    let button = UIButton()
    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func setupView() {
        view.addSubview(button)
        button.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.center.equalToSuperview()
        }
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        button.setTitle("test", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.red, for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didPress), for: .touchDown)
    }

    @objc func didPress() {
        delegate?.goToProfile() //delegate is nil
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupView()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

I don't know what is going on and it keeps giving me a nil delegate in HomeViewController (see comments in code).
Any ideas?

UPDATE

as @purpose mentioned about the `HomeTabBarCoordinator` being dealocated from the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` i changed the appDelegate function to the following but still have the same issue. How can i keep a strong ref. to `let about = HomeTabBarCoordinator()`

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var appCoordinator: TabAppCoordinator?
    let tabBarController = UITabBarController()

    let about = HomeTabBarCoordinator()

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.


        let one = deGenericize(about)
        appCoordinator = TabAppCoordinator(tabBarController: tabBarController, tabs: [one])
        appCoordinator?.start()


        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The offending code:

```
let about = HomeTabBarCoordinator()
```

What does it do? It creates a local variable and stores a `HomeTabBarCooordinator()` object inside.
What does it do once `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions)` goes? It deinits of course, since no new strong reference is created(its a good thing delegate is declared!).

You probably thought

```
public init<T: TabCoordinator>(_ tabCoordinator: T) {
    rootController = tabCoordinator.rootController
    tabBarItem = tabCoordinator.tabBarItem
}
```

would save you. Lets see whether `rootController` Or `tabBarItem` strongly reference our `HomeTabBarCoordinator`:

```
class HomeTabBarCoordinator: NSObject, TabCoordinator {
    var rootController: UINavigationController
    var tabBarItem: UITabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "About", image: UIImage(named: "AboutTabBarIcon"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "AboutTabBarIcon_Filled"))
    let homeVC: HomeViewController

    override init() {
        self.homeVC = HomeViewController()
        self.rootController = UINavigationController()
        super.init()
        rootController.viewControllers = [homeVC]
        rootController.tabBarItem = tabBarItem
        homeVC.delegate = self //is being set properly when i add a breakpoint here
    }
}
```

Nope, they don’t. Bye bye `HomeTabBarCoordinator`! So `delegate` becomes nil.

> How can i keep a strong ref. to let about = HomeTabBarCoordinator()

Putting it in a class which is itself strongly referenced is enough. Any reference which is not declared weak/unowned is strong and will survive incase the encasing class survives.

And `AppDelegate` is as sure as you can get that it won‘t deinit on its own.

Comment: oh ok i undestand, but even when i declare the `HomeTabBarCoordinator` outside the function, i still have the same issue. I will edit the question with the updated code.

Comment: `print("Delegate: \(delegate != nil)")` prints `Delegate: true` after the fix. If you think the fix made the delegate stay non-nil please accept the answer.